# Prevent a read-only checkbox from calling a event handler?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, checkboxfor

I have a list of checkboxes with the same syntax below, some of them are read-only:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SrsSettingList[i].LeftPickup, new{ @class= "chkSRSPickup"})
```

First I want to mention that I cant use "disabled" atrribute in this case. Please dont tell me to do that. Below is my event handler when I click on the checkbox:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.chkSRSPickup', function () {
```

blah blah...

```
    });
```

I dont want to call the function when I click on read-only checkboxes. How can I do that?

Comment: Whats wrong with handling that at the beginning of the function? Just return if its marked as readonly

Comment: Yeah, that would be my second way to fix the problem. Still let it call the event handler and check if the element has 'read-only' attribute and then return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) like

```
$(document).on('click', '.chkSRSPickup:not([readonly])', function () {
```

Comment: @MinhNguyen, dont forget to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem/was helpful